# How to get multiple values from SOAP XML String in Java

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing

I have a SOAP XML as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bcs:IntegrationEnquiryResultMsg>
            <ResultHeader>
                <cbs:ResultCode>0</cbs:ResultCode>
                <cbs:ResultDesc>Operation successfully.</cbs:ResultDesc>
            </ResultHeader>
            <IntegrationEnquiryResult>
                <bcs:Subscriber>
                    <bcs:SupplementaryOffering>
                        <bcc:OfferingKey>
                            <bcc:OfferingID>14205004</bcc:OfferingID>
                            <bcc:PurchaseSeq>300000000856956</bcc:PurchaseSeq>
                        </bcc:OfferingKey>
                    </bcs:SupplementaryOffering>
                    <bcs:SupplementaryOffering>
                        <bcc:OfferingKey>
                            <bcc:OfferingID>20220504</bcc:OfferingID>
                            <bcc:PurchaseSeq>300000000850496</bcc:PurchaseSeq>
                        </bcc:OfferingKey>
                    </bcs:SupplementaryOffering>
                    <bcs:SupplementaryOffering>
                        <bcc:OfferingKey>
                            <bcc:OfferingID>14205003</bcc:OfferingID>
                            <bcc:PurchaseSeq>300000000853681</bcc:PurchaseSeq>
                        </bcc:OfferingKey>
                    </bcs:SupplementaryOffering>
                </bcs:Subscriber>
            </IntegrationEnquiryResult>
        </bcs:IntegrationEnquiryResultMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would want to get the values of `OfferingID`. There could be multiple as in this case there are 3. I have tried the code below but I only get the first one.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(getString("bcc:OfferingID", rootElement));

    protected static String getString(String tagName, Element element) {
        NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        for (Node node : iterable(list)) {
            if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
                NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();

                if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
                    return subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static Iterable<Node> iterable(final NodeList nodeList) {
        return () -> new Iterator<Node>() {

            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index < nodeList.getLength();
            }

            @Override
            public Node next() {
                if (!hasNext())
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                return nodeList.item(index++);
            }
        };
    }

In this case, I only get `14205004`. Where am I missing a step?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a `node` variable in the for loop of your `getString` method which you don't use, instead you keep using the same element `list.item(0)`
2. You return immediately after the first iteration, so even if you fix the above issue withe `node` variable you will get only the first because you return on the first iteration
3. Your method returns a string where it should return a list of strings

Something like below might be what you want:

```
protected static List<String> getString(String tagName, Element element) {
    NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (Node node : iterable(list)) {
        result.add(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }

    return result;
}
```